# WPF: One way binding to source from ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, selecteditem

I have a ListBox whose ItemSource is a List where X is defined as:

```
public class X
{
    public string FullPath { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel is

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<X> MyList { get; set; }
    public X MyItem { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyList = new List<X>
        {
            new X { FullPath = "q:\\temp\\x1.png"},
            new X { FullPath = "q:\\temp\\x2.png"}
        };
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Bind1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bind1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding MyItem.FullPath, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding MyItem, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullPath}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This works when I used the keyboard up and down arrows in the ListBox (the image from the path selected in the ListBox shows up in the <Image>). However, when I click an item with the mouse, the item I click is not selected in the ListBox (the mouse click has no effect). The correct image shows up in the image very briefly (a fraction of a second) then the original image is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. With the given code, it runs perfectly on my system.

Comment: I just ran your code in my system and it works fine, both click and keyboard navigation event works fine. You may need to set a width and height for your image and stretch to fill in case the original width and height of the image is very big.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `StackPanel`, while the `Image` changes upon selection change in the `ListBox`, the size of the `Image` control may change, hence also the location of the `ListBox`.

Such case may cause an effect that the list item you click on not be the same item when you release the mouse button, as the item location changed.

There are many workaround, e.g. fix the size of the `Image` control, use `Grid` to define a layout, or simply put the `Image` after the `ListBox` in the `StackPanel`

Comment: Thank you - that is, indeed, the problem.